# Looking for other operating system during installation

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, usb, windows-10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 from a USB.

I shrunk my Windows 10 partition and formatted my usb as fat32. When it starts installing it says "Looking for other operating System" and when I click that it says "Invalid access to Fat32...".

I create a swap and mount partition ("/") as Primary.

Look here: https://askubuntu.com/q/710613/431955. It's very similar.

Comment: How did you create the install USB (for 14.04)? Why was the USB formatted to fat32 (and using what utility)?

Comment: I followed this: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. The program (Pen Drive's Linux USB Installer) auto formats to FAT32.

Comment: Try **rufus**, and set 'Partition scheme' to GPT. (https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Comment: That didn't work either. I just reinstalled Windows 10. Ubuntu installed fine after that. Thanks for the help!